# $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}(+,.),c\in\mathbb{R}(+,*)$ then $ c\cdot(a,b)=(c\cdot a , c\cdot b)$ or $(c*a,c*b)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have a vector space of Complex numbers $\mathbb{C}(+,\cdot)$ and $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}(+,.)$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}(+, *) $ and  $\mathbb{C}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ can we write $$c\cdot(a,b) = (c\cdot a , c\cdot b)\mathrm{~~or~~} c\cdot(a,b) = (c*a,c*b)?$$

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)$ belongs to the vector space of complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}(+,\cdot)$ over $\mathbb{R}(+,*)$ then, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. For instance, we can say $(a,b)$ represents the complex number $a+b\iota$, where $a,b$ are reals. $c$ belongs to the vector space of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}(+,*)$.

First consider the LHS,$$c\cdot(a,b)\qquad\mathrm{where,~}c\in\mathbb{R}(+,\cdot)\mathrm{~and~}(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}(+,\cdot).$$
We use the notation $``\cdot"$ because we are performing scalar multiplication under $\mathbb{C}(+,\cdot)$. This is equal to
$$(c~\underline{?}~a,c~\underline{?}~b)\qquad\mathrm{where,~}c,a,b\in\mathbb{R}(+,*).$$
Since we are now performing multiplication under $\mathbb{R}(+,*)$, we write
$$c\cdot(a,b)=(c*a,c*b).$$